# reverse words in a given string in python

Tags: python, string, data-structures, reverse

I have written the code in python it works fine if I give integer as an input but it does not when string is given.

Example -

**Input:**

```
2
i.like.this.program.very.much
pqr.mno
```

**Expected Output:**

```
much.very.program.this.like.i
mno.pqr
```

But the output which I get is same as input. The string is not getting reversed.
The code I have written is -

```
t=int(input())
for i in range(t):
    string1=input()
    li1=string1.split()
    li2=li1[::-1]
    output=' '.join(li2)
    print(output)
```

After running for the above input I get -

**Output:**

```
i.like.this.program.very.much
pqr.mno
```

Comment: Whatever your solution is, in the first line you're converting the input to an integer by calling `int()`, so it is expected that this will only work properly for integers.

Comment: What is pqr.mno and 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Cause of Wrong Output

The reason your program doesn't work correctly is because you are trying to split the string at *space* character  which is the default for `split()` when no parameter is specified. But you are really looking to split your string at `'.'` character.

So when you try `string1.split()` , the list you get is -

```
['i.like.this.program.very.much']
```

while what we really want to get the correct output is -

```
['i', 'like', 'this', 'program', 'very', 'much']
```

which we get correctly using `string1.split('.')`, that is splitting the string at `.` character and then reversing the string. Do note that while joining the string, we would have to join it using `.` as well.

---

So you should modify your code as follows.

#### Correct Code -

```
t=int(input())
for i in range(t):
    string1=input()
    li1=string1.split('.') #<-- Notice the parameter specified here. It will now split at `.` character
    li2=li1[::-1]          # Reverse the list
    output='.'.join(li2)   # Convert back into string. Again notice, we are joining at . character to get expected output
    print(output)
```

**Input :**

```
2
i.like.this.program.very.much
pqr.mno
```

**Output :**

```
much.very.program.this.like.i
mno.pqr
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Agreed !! This is the most pythonic way to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input("Enter string here = ")
l1=s.split
l1.reverse()
print(l1)
```